# "ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again" - Inside docker container

Tags: git, docker, ssh, dockerfile, docker-machine

I meet a strange problem like this. I need to start an container and clone github project via ssh in side container i just created. Sometime git clone perfect, and there is no trouble. But some time it can't and say this:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Try again
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I tried a lot of ways, like change mys `/etc/resolv.conf` by add google DNS, echo google DNS to `/etc/resolv.conf` inside container, restart docker, reinstall docker but no luck..
My git clone container join in to a docker user define bridge network. I think network is one of my problem but i don't know what exactly happen.
Another notice, everything work fine if i run it in local - ubuntu os. Problem only happen on my `Linode` serve 
There is anyone meet this problem ? Please help me...

Comment: For someone who searching for this issue. I used the CentOS server. Just witch to use Ubuntu, then the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a [lish shell session](https://www.linode.com/docs/networking/using-the-linode-shell-lish/), try, as [suggested here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/forge/could-not-resolve-hostname-bitbucketorg):

```
ssh -Tvvv git@github.com
```

And do a [traceroute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Traceroute) to see where the resolution fails.

Comment: Thank for your response, i have tried debug conenct this way anf it hanging at the time connect to github... Coun't get any response or error wanning...

Comment: @TruongDang Do you have any ~/.ssh/config file?

Comment: Yes.. Here is what i did for my docker iamge. It work well in local machine `echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\tIdentityFile /root/.ssh/id_rsa\n\tAddKeysToAgent yes\n" > /root/.ssh/config`

Comment: @TruongDang Is your private SSH key passphrase protected?

Comment: Really thank for you reply ^^. No, I don't need passphrase, i clone project automatic. So, i need to set empty passphrase...

Comment: @TruongDang OK so AddKeysToAgent might not be needed on Linode side. Does a `ping github.com` works (from Linode)?